# Open existing notes in Plasma

Tags: kde, plasma, kde5, plasma5

I have note files on `.local/share/plasma_notes` from Plasmoid Sticky Notes:

```
ls  .local/share/plasma_notes/
3a8ccf28-69f5-4cf9-a3eb-5d206e9441  880c660c-5719-4535-a004-bc0ebcf0e9  ced419ac-2c04-4771-af6c-282c59792d
51af8c5f-2a35-41da-8370-e8803eaf84  c6d0d3c2-0473-4337-837b-909ae7f360  fc3c79dc-afdf-4fd5-a9db-9ec08ca114
```

How to to open existing notes from such a files?

Using `plasma-desktop-5.4.3-1.fc23.x86_64`

Comment: They are just html files, so you can open them in a web browser.

Comment: Yup, In fact, I've just did that, I've opened on a browser and copied and pasted on a new note, but I was looking for a smarter and more natural way of do it :)

Comment: I guess if you want to parse them in bulk you could  send them through `w3m` or similar. e.g. to dump them in a single file, `w3m -T text/html ~/.local/share/plasma_notes/* > parsed_notes`, or to dump them in separate files, `for i in ~/.local/share/plasma_notes/*; do w3m -T text/html $i > ${i}_parsed ; done`.

Answer (score 1):

To parse them like @Sparhawk said, works fine.
What I do to get my existing notes back is a bit longer, but keeps the layout:

1. First re-create the same number of empty notes you like to restore.
2. Get the filenames of the notes to restore from ~/.local/share/plasma_notes/
3. Open the file ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
4. Find entries which look like this :

   [Containments][110][Applets][131][Configuration][General]
   noteId=e6abe1c5-fd0b-4909-ac40-1595073d5a
5. Replace the noteId with the filename (which is the Id of course) from ~/.local/share/plasma_notes/ for the note to restore.
6. Repeat this for every note lost, afterwards you can delete files from ~/.local/share/plasma_notes/ which have only been created to get the empty notes
7. log-out and back in from plasma, to load the modified applets